# Problemas con las diferencias de una Activity y DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema y no lo consigo solucionar de ninguna forma.

Antes tenía una `Activity` llamada `MasInformacion` y realizaba lo siguiente:

```
public class MasInformacion extends Activity {

    private TextView editTextNombre ,editTextFecha, editTextZodiaco, editTextEdad, editTextDiasrestantes;
    private Bundle extras;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mas_informacion);

        editTextNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
        editTextFecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);
        editTextZodiaco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextZodiaco);
        editTextEdad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextEdad);
        editTextDiasrestantes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextDiasrestantes);

        // Recupera en un Objeto Bundle si tiene valores que fueron pasados como
        // parametro de una actividad.
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
            editTextNombre.setText(extras.getString("nombre"));
            editTextFecha.setText(extras.getString("fecha"));
            editTextZodiaco.setText(extras.getString("zodiaco"));
            editTextEdad.setText(extras.getString("edad"));
            editTextDiasrestantes.setText(extras.getString("diasrestantes"));
        }
    }

    /// comprueba el estado de EditarPersona

    public boolean estadoEditarPersona() {
        // Si extras es diferente a null es porque tiene valores. En este caso
        // es porque se quiere editar una persona.
        if (extras != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Y desde `MainActivity`

```
public void masInformacion(int p_id){
        Persona persona;
        try{
            persona = baseDatos.getPersona(p_id);
            // Se dirige a la actividad MasInformacion
            Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(this, MasInformacion.class);

            // Carga los datos para mostrar en MasInformacion
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("id", p_id);
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("nombre", persona.getNombre());
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("fecha", persona.getFecha());
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("zodiaco", persona.getZodiaco());
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("edad", persona.getEdad());
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("diasrestantes", persona.getDiasrestantes());
            startActivityForResult(actividad_editarPersona, CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (getResources().getString(R.string.error_mostrarinformacion)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }
```

Utilizando el método así:

```
masInformacion((int)info.id);
```

Y todo funcionaba perfectamente. Pero ahora he cambiado esa `Activity` por un `DialogFragment`, este:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private TextView editTextNombre ,editTextFecha, editTextZodiaco, editTextEdad, editTextDiasrestantes;
    Bundle extras;

    static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {

        return new MyDialogFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mas_informacion, container, false);

        editTextNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
        editTextFecha = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);
        editTextZodiaco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextZodiaco);
        editTextEdad = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEdad);
        editTextDiasrestantes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextDiasrestantes);


        // Recupera en un Objeto Bundle si tiene valores que fueron pasados como
        // parametro de una actividad.

        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

        if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
            editTextNombre.setText(extras.getString("nombre"));
            editTextFecha.setText(extras.getString("fecha"));
            editTextZodiaco.setText(extras.getString("zodiaco"));
            editTextEdad.setText(extras.getString("edad"));
            editTextDiasrestantes.setText(extras.getString("diasrestantes"));

        }
        return view;
    }

    /// comprueba el estado de EditarPersona

    public boolean estadoEditarPersona() {
        // Si extras es diferente a null es porque tiene valores. En este caso
        // es porque se quiere editar una persona.
        if (extras != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Y el problema viene ahora, que no se como modificar `MainActivity` correctamente, hago lo siguiente pero no sirve, ya que no lee la información de mi `Sqlite`:

```
    void showDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = fm.findFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        masInformacion((int)info.id);


        DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.show(ft, "tag");
    }

public void masInformacion(int p_id){
        Persona persona;
        try{
            persona = baseDatos.getPersona(p_id);
            // Se dirige a la actividad MasInformacion
            Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(this, MyDialogFragment.class);

            // Carga los datos para mostrar en MasInformacion
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("id", p_id);
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("nombre", persona.getNombre());
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("fecha", persona.getFecha());
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("zodiaco", persona.getZodiaco());
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("edad", persona.getEdad());
            actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("diasrestantes", persona.getDiasrestantes());
            startActivityForResult(actividad_editarPersona, CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (getResources().getString(R.string.error_mostrarinformacion)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }
```

Y utilizo el método así: `showDialog();`

Lo único que consigo así es que se abra mi `DialogFragment` pero sin leer los datos de la `Sqlite` y además con este error en `logcat`

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {otrointento.dos/otrointento.dos.MyDialogFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` debes declarar tus Actividades:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

pero el problema aquí es que intentas abrir un `Fragment` por medio de un `Intent` como si fuese `Activity`

```
   Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(this, MyDialogFragment.class);
```

Esto solo se puede realizar con clases que extiendan  de `Activity` o `AppCompatActivity`.

Lo que tienes que realizar es una transacción ya que tu clase extiende de `Fragment`.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
```

---

Me parece que el método `public void masInformacion(int p_id){` en realidad debe mostrar el `Activity` `MasInformacion` por lo tanto solo cambia la clase que abrirá el `Intent`.

```
        // Se dirige a la actividad MasInformacion
        //Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(this, MyDialogFragment.class);
        Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(this, MasInformacion.class);
```

---

### Actualización:

El usuario desea abrir el Fragment no la Activity, para esto se crea un método:

```
public void muestraDialogo(int p_id) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = fm.findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(p_id, this);
    newFragment.show(ft, "tag");
}
```

la parte importante es inicializar los valores necesarios para esto se modifica el método `newInstance()` del Fragment, recibira el contexto para instanciar la base de datos y obtener los datos de la persona de acuerdo al id:

```
static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int p_id, Context ctx) {

    MyDialogFragment frag = new MyDialogFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    mContext = ctx;
    Persona persona;
    baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
    persona = baseDatos.getPersona(p_id);

    bundle.putInt("id", p_id);
    bundle.putString("nombre", persona.getNombre());
    bundle.putString("fecha", persona.getFecha());
    bundle.putString("zodiaco", persona.getZodiaco());
    bundle.putString("ruta_imagen", persona.getRutaImagen());

    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    return frag;
   // return new MyDialogFragment();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55222/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-problemas-con-las-diferencias-de-una-activity-y).